# Populate a combobox and get results on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am getting results from the database to populate on the Combobox and that's everything right. What I am trying to do next is after chose something from that Combobox it'll show on the DataGridView with some info of what I selected from CB.

This is the code that I am using right now

```
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "....."
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
            SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SQLDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
            While SQLDataReader.Read
                Dim fileType = SQLDataReader.GetString(0)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ComboBox1.Items.Add(fileType)
            End While
            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Comment: First this line `DataGridView1.DataSource = ComboBox1.Items.Add(fileType)` is incorect; how many column you want to show in DataGridView ?

Comment: I wanna group it by Filetype, but the goal is to show the column Filetype and 2 more columns

Comment: You can Fill `Combox` at First, and create another methode to fill `DataGridWiew` when `Combox` change value.

Comment: Basically a method called for example DisplayInfo() and then creating there a query that gives me the Info that I want by clicking on the Combobox?

Comment: Yes exactly what i mean

Comment: I already have this method created with the query that I want to use. But now what do I do to after selecting something from the CB it'll just displays the info that I am looking for?

Comment: I've made some testes and I can do this if I use a button to click with the method inside of it. But want I want is just showing the info by clicking on the selected field on the CB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Fill `ComboBox` with your code like :

```
SQLCon = New SqlConnection
SQLCon.ConnectionString = "....."
Try
    SQLCon.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
    SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
    SqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    While SqlDataReader.Read
        Dim fileType = SqlDataReader.GetString(0)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(fileType)
    End While
    SQLCon.Close()
Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    SQLCon.Dispose()
End Try
```

And create `Function` that return Data from Database to `DataGridView` where `ComboBox` change data like this :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    DataGridView1.DataSource = FillDataGridView(ComboBox1.Text)
End Sub

Function FillDataGridView(valueComboBox As String) As DataTable
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "....."
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile where Filetype=@Filetype"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Filetype", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valueComboBox
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        SQLCon.Close()
        Return table
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return table
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

You can change query to give more field as you like

Comment: I am using the code that I've posted in Form1. If I fill it in the ComboBox it won't display anything

Comment: Another thing, in the End Function gives me a message "Function 'FillDataGridView' doesn't return a value on all codes paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used". What can I do about it?

Comment: to correct this warning, t declare `DataTable` out of `Try Catch` and i return table in exception,view answer.